# Word vba - How can I store string values in a module?

Tags: vba, ms-word

the title may not be appropriate because I don't really know how I should put this.
I have a template where I have a "Module1" module and a "ThisDocument" code.
Module1 contains the following code to pick up values from the registry. 
I pick up these values from ThisDocument code.

What I want is to move the code from ThisDocument over to it's own module. And being able to access the values from all other modules or subs.

Right now, ThisDocument has code that looks a little like this:

```
regPath = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "Path")
regString = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "String")
regStrFirstname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Firstname")
regStrLastname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Lastname")
regStrInitials = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Initials")
regStrFullname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Fullname")
```

So, instead of having this code in ThisDocument, I would like to have this code in a separate Module and being able to access the values from ThisDocument directly. This way I can pick up the values from, say a form as well. Populate textboxes with the values etc.

How should I do this?

Module1 looks like this:

```
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileSection Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetPrivateProfileSectionA" (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, _
ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function WritePrivateProfileSection Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"WritePrivateProfileSectionA" (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

'// INI CONTROLLING PROCEDURES
'reads an Ini string
Public Function ReadIni(Filename As String, Section As String, Key As String) As String
Dim RetVal As String * 255, v As Long
v = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", RetVal, 255, Filename)
ReadIni = Left(RetVal, v + 0)
End Function

'reads an Ini section
Public Function ReadIniSection(Filename As String, Section As String) As String
Dim RetVal As String * 255, v As Long
v = GetPrivateProfileSection(Section, RetVal, 255, Filename)
ReadIniSection = Left(RetVal, v + 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the variables functions. You basically want global variables accessible everywhere. The way to do that is to capsulate the variables.

In Module1 (or a new module) add:

```
Function regPath()
        regPath = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "Path")
End Function
```

Hope it helps.

If you want to get even more sophisticated you can work with objects.

Comment: So does this mean that I need to declare a Function for each of the registry values? regPath, regFirstName, regLastName etc?

Comment: Yes, one function for each registry value.

Comment: Is it not possible to make a Function with a parameter? That way you could just pass the Registry and Path variables as parameters to that Funtion....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd recommend you get rid of the API calls and just use the built-in registry functions in VBA of `GetSetting`, `SaveSetting`, `GetAllSettings` and `DeleteSetting`. You can learn more about them here: [Maintain Custom Settings Using the Windows Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155437(office.10).aspx). One of the immediate benefits of doing this, besides the fact that it's easy, is that if you end up working with Word 2010 x64, you don't have to maintain two sets of API calls, one for x64 and one for x86.

Now on to your question. It depends if your code is going to run in a global template or by itself. If it's in a global template, you'd use a sub routine in any module (like Module1) called `AutoExec` - you can put anything you want in that subroutine, like initilization of global variables. If it's not a global template (i.e. you're just going to open it sometimes and don't want it to always open when you start Word), then you would use `AutoOpen` instead. Any code in `AutoOpen` will run automatically (assuming you've handled security settings) when your macro-enabled document is opened.

So you could have something like this in Module1:

```
''# Put this at the top of the module
Public regPath As String
Public regString As String
Public regStrFirstname  As String
Public regStrLastname As String 
Public regStrInitials As String
Public regStrFullname As String

Sub AutoOpen()
    ''# Use your current API calls to the registry or the VBA calls to the registry (above)
    regPath = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "Path") 
    regString = ReadIni(File, "Registry", "String") 
    regStrFirstname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Firstname") 
    regStrLastname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Lastname") 
    regStrInitials = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Initials") 
    regStrFullname = ReadIni(File, "Fields", "Fullname")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have an INI file where the registry paths are written. This code ReadIni reads this and passes it to an objShell.RegRead.
Are you familiar with objShell.RegRead? Is this what I should replace?

Also, how is it different from using AutoOpen than Document_New ?
That seems to do the job so far. AutoOpen() probably needs to be put in ThisDocument? It probably won't do anything if I leave it in a Module?

Comment: @Kenny Bones: The `GetSetting` and other functions can be used for both the Windows Registry and/or INI files, that's one of the great things about them. Maybe I spoke too soon on that as your real question was about how to initialize global variables from a standard module. `AutoOpen()` is different from `Document_New()` in that a new document doesn't need to be opened to trigger it. If yours is a template, it will trigger when that template opens. It can go in a module of any name (like *Module3*, for example), not in *ThisDocument*.

Comment: But are there any advantages to using GetSetting for both ini files and registry? Could you provide some code showing how to read ini files as well?

I just tried to add a simple Private Sub AutoOpen() with just a message box in it and put it in Module1. ThisDocument () contains nothing right now. But it doesn't trigger and I see no message box. Only when I open the template, not when I double click the template (new document) This is Word 2007. It's already been set for some 2000 users and I have no plan in changing that setting really. The template area has been added to trusted locations.

Comment: @Kenny Bones: Again, I may have injected more than you asked for with the `GetSetting` stuff. Ask another question of the community so that more people than me have a chance to answer (if you like, I can delete that portion from this post to just focus on your immedate question). On the `AutoOpen`, that is the expected behavior as it is for the template/document, not for documents created from a template. If you put your template in your STARTUP folder (on mine it is: *C:\Users\Otaku\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP*) and then re-open Word, you should see your message box.